# 3-Layer Architecture c# asp.net connect logic layer with DAL using interface

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to create an c# ASP.net MVC app with 3 layer architecture.

At the moment I have the following layers.

1. MVC Project
2. Business/Logic Layer.
3. DAL (Data Access Layer)

What is the best way to communicate with the DAL Layer? I thought maybe using interfaces?

Does someone have ideas?

Comment: Create a `Common` layer and insert your `DTO` class there. Add `Common` to all other layers. Done.

Comment: Interfaces is the right way to go.  If you know/understand IoC.

Comment: `private readonly IAppointment _appointment = DAL.Customer.CustomerFunctions();` I'm trying to instantiate a Interface, but now, my logic layer needs to have a reference to my DAL, How can I solve that issue?

Comment: Look into DI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Alright, in my Logic layer I have now a field `private IAppointment _appointment;` And a constructor `public AppointmentLogic(IAppointment appointment)
        {
            _appointment = appointment;
        }`

Comment: I have added a scope in Program.cs `builder.Services.AddScoped<IAppointment, AppointmentFunctions>();`

Comment: But how can I use this implentation in my AppointmentsController, the MVC Controller?

Comment: Because `private readonly AppointmentLogic appointmentLogic;` this is not working, and I also can't instansiate this appointmentLogic because It needs a IAppointment as parameter

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I solved this problem by creating interfaces for my logic functions and inject these in my MVC Controller.

Everything now works fine.